# How to host WCF service in IIS 5.1?

Tags: wcf, iis, deployment

I use VS2008 and .NET 3.5.

This is my case:

1) External service:

I use external service (don't have any knowledge about its code; it's black box for me) and call its method that takes several arguments. One of them is address of WCF service that I should wrote (see 2)). The call looks as following:

```
string Url = "http://public-ip:8072/Service.svc";
string content = extClient.Method1(Url, email, param1, param2...);
```

Somewhere in the body of Method1 they call my service from 2).

2) My service:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public const string ReplyAction = "http://public-ip:8072/Message_ReplyAction";
    public const string RequestAction = "http://public-ip:8072/Message_RequestAction";

    public Message SetData(Message requestXml)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
      <add prefix="http://public-ip:8072/"/>
    </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Parus.ServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://local-ip:8072/Service.svc"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="Parus.ServiceBehavior" name="Parus.Service">
      <endpoint address="http://public-ip:8072/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Parus.IService">
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

My service works when I use it locally, but doesn't when I expose it to the world. I mean the Method1 from 1) doesn't call it at all. I've tried different things but nothing happens so far. It doesn't work when firewall is off. Also, it doesn't work when the exception for port 8072 for firewall is added.

I suppose there's something wrong I did in Web.config file or missed some settings in IIS. You can pay attention to public-ip and local-ip addresses in Web.config file. Maybe I made mistake with them. I'm not sure.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

When a service works locally but not via the public ip address it is normally one of two things:

- The firewall is blocking the request. Here I see that you wrote that you opened the port. Try testing it with telnet, maybe there are several layers blocking the port and you only opened one.
- The configuration. You mix the use of public and private IP addresses in your web.config, try setting everything to the public IP address.

Comment: I want my service to be exposed not only locally, but to the internet as well.

Comment: I've set up all addresses in my Web.config file to be the same - public IP, but everything is the same, which means my service was not executed.

Comment: I'm really not sure what to do next.

Comment: Check the iis log to see if the request is reaching iis

Comment: There's nothing in IIS log about external call.